# When I am using Gmail API ,I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader

Tags: gson, noclassdeffounderror, gmail-api, jsonreader

I am following 
[Google Developer's Doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android)
.I have included all mentioned jars but at runtime I getting this..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory.createJsonParser(GsonFactory.java:86)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory.createJsonParser(GsonFactory.java:76)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at com.example.gmailquickstart.ApiAsyncTask.getDataFromApi(ApiAsyncTask.java:73)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at com.example.gmailquickstart.ApiAsyncTask.doInBackground(ApiAsyncTask.java:39)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at com.example.gmailquickstart.ApiAsyncTask.doInBackground(ApiAsyncTask.java:1)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-19 12:42:06.416: E/AndroidRuntime(14215):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

The line where I am getting this error

```
ListLabelsResponse listResponse =
                mActivity.mService.users().labels().list(user).execute();
```

Comment: "I included all the mentioned jars...".  Somehow, you didn't - you're missing the GSON .jar.  Q: How are you building your application?  With Android Studio?  Q: Where are you running the application?  In an emulator, or an actual handset?  The problem is in your "build", not the code itself.

Comment: @paulsm4 I am building my app in eclipse and I am running app in moto-e(5.1) and ASUS(4.4.2). I had included gson.jar but it didn't worked so I have remove.

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks, when I am including  'google-http-client-gson-1.20.0.jar' and 'gson-2.1.jar' it is working.